# What scrollview and imageview settings should be used to display a zoomable picture in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I am getting some strange behaviour when trying to zoom in on a png in an image view, inside a scroll view.  I think I've set the constraints or settings in my utilities pane wrong.  What should they be if I want to see the entire picture first and then zoom in on it?

The image renders, but then when I try to pinch zoom in and out, only the height of the picture changes bigger or smaller, with the width stuck at the iPhone screen width.  If I fiddle enough however, I can zoom in further, but everything gets distorted and spinney.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code I have in the View Controller implementation file now:

```
@interface ZooViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation ZooViewController
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize scrollView;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width,     self.imageView.image.size.height);

}

-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    return self.imageView;
}

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


-(void)viewDidUnload{

    [self setImageView:nil];
    [self setScrollView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

Comment: Is there some code you think is responsible that you can post? Maybe a pic/screen capture of the issue?

Comment: https://cocoadevblog.s3.amazonaws.com/005/ImageZooming.zip

Comment: @NANNAV, thanks for that code!  I'm confused though as to how the settings in the storyboard utility panel relate to the code itself.  Does the code overwrite the settings, or vice versa?  Sorry for the beginner questions..

Answer (score 2):

First set image content mode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

```
[self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

After that set scrollview content size

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.areaImageView.frame.size;
```

Don't forget to set scrollview delegates

```
 // For supporting zoom,
 scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
 scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;

 ...

 // Implement a single scroll view delegate method
 - (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
   return imageView;
  }
```

Comment: I think maybe I've checked or unchecked things in the storyboard utilities panel that I shouldn't have?  Like maybe things in the view or scrollview utilities?  Right now in the simulator it only moves the image up and down but only zooms in sporadically (like in one attempt out of 15).

Comment: Are there specific width and height sizes that I'm supposed to use for the Scroll and Image settings to make them work with each other? Anyways, I added the code above.  Thanks!!